# faster redraw of pygtk drawing area?

Tags: python, pygtk, drawable, redraw, pixmap

I'm creating a paint program based on [this](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/scribblesimple.py) program. Dragging the mouse faster results in spotty brush strokes, so I'm wondering if there is a faster way to redraw the drawing area.
This is the current redraw function. It is already utilizing `widget.queue_draw_area` and the screen is redrawn from a pixmap.

```
def expose_event(self, widget, event):
    x , y, width, height = event.area
    widget.window.draw_drawable(widget.get_style().fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL],
                                self.pixmap, x, y, x, y,
                                width, height)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping track of the last position of the mouse and then drawing a continuous line from the last position to the current position, instead of drawing one brush shape at the current position.